# PhpStorm SCSS file watcher: "sass not found"

Tags: rubygems, sass, phpstorm

I don't get it: i configured a scss file watcher, but every time compiling starts, PhpStorm throws this errors:

```
/Users/peter_goebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/scss --no-cache --update style.scss:style.css
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find sass (>= 0) amongst [long list of gems...] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/peter_goebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/scss:18
    from /Users/peter_goebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14
```

What am i doing wrong?

A few screenshots that might be helpful:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, i figured it out.

I had to set this environment variable:

```
GEM_PATH : /Users/peter_goebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
```